# How can I run a service on a separate thread?

Tags: android, android-service

I need to run a service on a separate thread. This is because it accesses a webservice which can take 5 - 10 seconds, and I don't want to get ANR. I will also be binding to this service. I have found a way to launch the service in a separate thread with something like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                //Launch and/or Bind to service here
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

However I believe this only runs the starting code in a new thread while the service itself runs in the main thread. So how would I actually run all the code from the service in another thread?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `IntentService`

> IntentService is a base class for
>   Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on
>   demand. Clients send requests through
>   startService(Intent) calls; the
>   service is started as needed, handles
>   each Intent in turn using a worker
>   thread, and stops itself when it runs
>   out of work

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply that would work for this scenario. However I also have another service monitoring the GPS every 200 ms and I do not want it to slow down the main thread. As this service relies on onLocationChanged being called, I do not want it to get killed as intent service will be. How would I run this is a seperate thread? Or would that be a seperate question?